# Use of unassigned local variable 'Random'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made an spawner in Unity but I got some errors:

error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'Random'

error CS1061: 'float' does not contain a definition for 'Range' and no accessible extension method 'Range' accepting a first argument of type 'float' could be found

all these error's says that this line of code:

```
float Random = Random.Range(0,100) / 100;
```

doesn't work.

Why these errors appeard?
How to repair it?

Comment: `Why these errors appeard` because you named your variable `Random` just like the type `Random` ... `How to repair it?` .. name your variable different

Comment: Also note that `Random.Range(0,100) / 100;` will always return `0` ^^ `Random.Range(int, int)` returns an `int` between `min` (0) and `max - 1` (99) .. then you do integer division `/ 100` -> always `0` .. you probably rather simply want `Random.Range(0f, 1f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I will post my assumption here

You named float Random witch is a class

Try naming it rnd like this:

```
 float rnd = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
```

Comment: I was so free to fix your code example as well ;)

Comment: Thanks :). This answer saved my game that I had to make today. This answer is very helpfull. So again, thanks.